# Find string VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, parsing, text

I have a text file with multiple different items that I need to grab from it.

Here is portion of the text file:

```
JOB_NUMBER                      XXXX-XX              TYPE: String               
                                                     SOURCE: User-Defined       
                                                     ACCESS: Full               
                                                     DESIGNATED: NO             
                                                     DESCRIPTION:               

CUSTOMER                        SAMPLE COMPANY       TYPE: String               
                                                     SOURCE: User-Defined       
                                                     ACCESS: Full               
                                                     DESIGNATED: NO             
                                                     DESCRIPTION:               

OVERBURN                        5.500000e-03         TYPE: Real Number          
                                                     SOURCE: User-Defined       
                                                     ACCESS: Full               
                                                     DESIGNATED: NO             
                                                     DESCRIPTION:
```

I need to find the string with JOB_NUMBER in it and grab the number "XXXX-XX" same with "CUSTOMER" but that will be a string not an integer.

This cannot be done by line number because it will be different every time.

Any suggestions would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx).

[Another example](http://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2010/05/Do-you-know-the-TextFieldParser.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Is there only going to be 1 job number and one customer string in each file?
If yes you could read the file to a string and extract like so:

```
Dim thefile As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\test.txt")
Dim jobnumber As String = Split(Split(thefile, "JOB_NUMBER")(1), "TYPE:")(0).Trim()
Dim customer As String = Split(Split(thefile, "CUSTOMER")(1), "TYPE:")(0).Trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

If those are fixed width columns, simply find the lines that begin with JOB_NUMBER and CUSTOMER and substring out the middle column, then trim the spaces.